# Docker 'core-dump' error when starting service

Tags: arm, systemd, services, docker

I'm using a Raspberry Pi **1** Model B.

I've just installed using the easy script:

`curl -sSL https://get.docker.com | sh`

install results:

```
# Executing docker install script, commit: 4957679
+ sudo -E sh -c apt-get update -qq >/dev/null
+ sudo -E sh -c apt-get install -y -qq apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl >/dev/null
+ sudo -E sh -c curl -fsSL "https://download.docker.com/linux/raspbian/gpg" | apt-key add -qq - >/dev/null
Warning: apt-key output should not be parsed (stdout is not a terminal)
+ sudo -E sh -c echo "deb [arch=armhf] https://download.docker.com/linux/raspbian stretch edge" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list
+ sudo -E sh -c apt-get update -qq >/dev/null
+ sudo -E sh -c apt-get install -y -qq --no-install-recommends docker-ce >/dev/null
If you would like to use Docker as a non-root user, you should now consider
adding your user to the "docker" group with something like:

  sudo usermod -aG docker jimjamz

Remember that you will have to log out and back in for this to take effect!

WARNING: Adding a user to the "docker" group will grant the ability to run
         containers which can be used to obtain root privileges on the
         docker host.
         Refer to https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/security/#docker-daemon-attack-surface
         for more information.
```

added my user to the docker group:

`sudo usermod -aG docker jimjamz`

logged out, logged back in and I wanted to confidence check docker:

`docker -v`

result:

`Docker version 18.09.0, build 4d60db4`

but when I want to use any other docker command:

`docker ps -a`

result:

`Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?`

checking the status of the docker service:

```
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) (Result: core-dump) since Sat 2019-01-26 14:45:07 UTC; 14min ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
  Process: 4314 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H unix:// (code=dumped, signal=SEGV)
 Main PID: 4314 (code=dumped, signal=SEGV)
      CPU: 668ms
```

checking the journal for further info:

`sudo journalctl -qxe | grep docker`

result:

```
Jan 26 14:44:33 JIMJAMZ-PI sudo[4215]:  jimjamz : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/jimjamz ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/docker ps -a
Jan 26 14:44:49 JIMJAMZ-PI sudo[4248]:     root : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/root ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/service docker restart
-- Subject: Unit docker.service has begun start-up
-- Unit docker.service has begun starting up.
Jan 26 14:44:53 JIMJAMZ-PI systemd[1]: docker.service: Main process exited, code=dumped, status=11/SEGV
-- Subject: Unit docker.service has finished shutting down
-- Unit docker.service has finished shutting down.
Jan 26 14:44:53 JIMJAMZ-PI systemd[1]: docker.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jan 26 14:44:53 JIMJAMZ-PI systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'core-dump'.
Jan 26 14:44:59 JIMJAMZ-PI sudo[4268]:     root : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/root ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/service docker start
-- Subject: Unit docker.service has begun start-up
-- Unit docker.service has begun starting up.
Jan 26 14:45:06 JIMJAMZ-PI systemd[1]: docker.service: Main process exited, code=dumped, status=11/SEGV
-- Subject: Unit docker.service has failed
-- Unit docker.service has failed.
Jan 26 14:45:06 JIMJAMZ-PI systemd[1]: docker.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jan 26 14:45:06 JIMJAMZ-PI systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'core-dump'.
-- Subject: Unit docker.service has finished shutting down
-- Unit docker.service has finished shutting down.
```

Set docker to auto-start:

`sudo systemctl enable docker`

When trying to start the service manually:

`systemctl start docker.service`

result:

`Failed to start docker.service: The name org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1 was not provided by any .service files`

Same problem still occurs after reboot.  The problem also occurs for root user.

Does this have something to do with the installation using `[arch=armhf]` instead of `[arch=arm32v6]`?

Comment: `Does this have something to do with` no .. .raspberry pi is armhf - I just installed docker on my pi3B - no issues at all ... trying on pi1B because I'm assuming that's what you actually have, since you mentioned only `B` .. no `1` `2` or `3`

Comment: yeah, looks like it fails on pi1 - perhaps you need a 2 or 3 for docker

Comment: Hi.  Thanks for your comment.  Sorry, I may not have fully understood all of your comment, but from what I can gather, it's not related to the architecture option specified (so `armhf` is correct?).  Also, I should have made it more clear that I am using a Raspberry Pi 1 Model B.  Sorry, I didn't realise there was a Model B for the later Pis.  So, you're saying this works on a Pi 3, but not on the Pi 1?  Interesting.  Strangely, I haven't come across any online search results similar to this, which could imply that no-one is using a Docker on a Pi 1?  That seems unlikely.

Comment: @Jaromanda X - Did you receive the same error on your Pi 1 Model B, as I did?  Or did you receive a different error?

Comment: Same error i.e. seg fault core dumped

Comment: I know for a fact that docker is used on pi 1's - though have never used it myself on a 1. Searching for  "raspberry pi docker core dump" I found [this issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/38175) which contains a fix  - i.e. use docker-ce 18.06.1 - instructions in that issue

Comment: I've looked at the "get docker" script, and it seems you can get a specific version of DOCKER by doing `curl -sSL https://get.docker.com | VERSION=18.06.1 sh`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *Please note a previous version of this answer recommended installing version `18.06.1` of docker-ce however this version does not include the patch for the `runc` CVE that allowed for container escape [as pointed out in the thread](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/38175#issuecomment-464916363). Versions `18.06.2` and `18.06.3` both reportedly work and are not vulnerable to [`CVE-2019-5736`](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2019-5736). Commands below have been updated accordingly.*

Newer docker versions don't seem to work on Raspbery 1 and Raspberry 0. I had the same issue. Found [this bug ticket](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/38175) which explained to install docker v18.06.2 to get to a working version.

```
sudo apt-get purge docker-ce
sudo apt-get install docker-ce=18.06.2~ce~3-0~raspbian
sudo systemctl enable docker && sudo systemctl start docker
```

Worked for me on a Raspberry 0...

Comment: I couldn't get 18.06.3 to work. Didn't test 18.06.2. But @DaveLak pointed out the vulnarability of 18.06.1 and that's a very important point. So I accepted the edit.

Comment: FWIW I did get 18.06.2 working on a Raspberry Pi 0 W and was able to, in part due to your answer here. Thanks @nnn

Comment: Ok, then we know that 18.06.2 works! I have to give it a try again. Did you try 18.06.3?

Comment: No, I did not. Only 18.06.2

Comment: I just tried 18.06.3. It does work on RPi 1.  Current version 18.09.0 (2019-05) does not work.